# How to make exactly one read syscall in Bash?

Tags: bash

What I want to do is process data when it arrives, independent of line breaks.

- When using `read -n $n` with a pipe on stdin, Bash makes one syscall `read (0, buf, 1)` per byte, which is too slow if the amount of data to be processed is not small (say, 1 MB or more).
- When using `read -N $n` Bash makes repeated syscalls `read (0, buf, <RestOf$n>)` until `$n` is reached, so I cannot start processing what is received so far.
- When using `read -N $n -t 0.1` I get an empty `$REPLY` even if some data has been read. That means: data is lost. Is this a bug or a feature of Bash?

So how can I make exactly one `read` syscall with an arbitrary `count` argument in `bash` and then process the input received so far ?

Comment: `read` in Bash is not a good tool to process "1 MB or more". What is your usage case?

Comment: @Kamil, The usage case is a preprocessor for `less` which, at most times, processes much less than 1 MB, but should also work with acceptable speed in case of larger input.

Comment: I don't know what it does but in general you should avoid `read` in text processing. Reasonable tools are `awk`, `sed`, `python`, `perl`, ...; or more specialized: `cut`, `tr`, `head`, ... Your preprocessor may be a Bash script that chains these tools together but using `read` and actually processing in Bash should not be your default choice if you want high throughput. If I knew the answer I would help you (and I hope somebody will); still I think *maybe* you're trying to find a way to elongate the blade in your Swiss Army knife, while the real solution is to get a machete.

Comment: @Kamil, basically, you are right. But for the majority of cases where `less` and its preprocessors are used, one does not need the highest possible performance: Sufficient performance is enough. One syscall per byte processed makes insufficient performance, but in general, bash is not particlularly slow. In particular, processing text in bash is faster than making one pair of fork/exec per line of text processed, for instance.

Comment: Note no tool I mentioned forks per line. A filter with `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` shebang runs one process. The same for `#!/bin/sed -f` or `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. They can process text better than Bash. But hey, whatever fits you.

Comment: @Kamil, of course no tool _by itself_ forks once per line - it depends on what the programmer does/needs and I just meant it as an example of _what else can happen_ in practice and may be slower than bash programming. By the way, I'm familiar with `sed` and `awk` and thus I know they cannot do what I want (process data when it arrives, independent of line breaks). But I don't know `python`. How would one make _exactly one read syscall_ in python ?